# Slick Slider - Rewind to first slide when reached the last

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slider, slick.js

I want to make Slick carousel rewind to the first slide when it reaches the last slide, i searched for a solution but didn't find any.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmo50w7n/1575/) for slick, i would like something like [the rewind feature of Owl Carousel](https://jsfiddle.net/L9mqq6pL/1/). I would use Owl carousel but Slick has some features that I need and Owl Carousel doesn't have. If anyone knows how to do this I'll be grateful

```js
$(".slider").slick({
  slidesToShow:1,
});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider span {
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<section class="slider">
  <span>slide1</span>
  <span>slide2</span>
  <span>slide3</span>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) you can just take out `{slidesToShow:1,}` to make your slider call look like `$(".slider").slick();`

Also, it looks like your jsfiddle that you shared is working but your integrated code snippet demo doesn't have jquery on it. Maybe that's your real issue?

Comment: I want the slide to rewind when reaches the last slide, just like owl carousel does, i don't understood what you mean't.

Comment: Slick carousel  automatically rewinds to the first one. Do you mean the rewinding action CSS? You didn't specify that in your question.

Comment: The normal behavior is infinite loop, what i want is rewind